# How to test if an element has class using Protractor?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I'm trying out Protractor to e2e test Angular app and haven't figured out how to detect if an element has a specific class or not.

In my case, the test clicks on submit button and now I want to know if form[name="getoffer"] has class .ngDirty. What may be the solutions?

```
describe('Contact form', function() {
    beforeEach(function(){
        browser.get('http://localhost:9000');
        element(by.linkText('Contact me')).click();
    });

    it('should fail form validation, all fields pristine', function() {
        element(by.css('.form[name="getoffer"] input[type="submit"]')).click();
        expect(element(by.name('getoffer'))).toHaveClass('ngDirty'); // <-- This line
    });
});
```

Answer (score 114, accepted):

One gotcha you have to look out for with using `toMatch()`, as in the accepted answer, is partial matches. For instance, let's say you have an element that might have the classes `correct` and `incorrect`, and you want to test that it has the class `correct`. If you were to use `expect(element.getAttribute('class')).toMatch('correct')`, that will return true even if the element has the `incorrect` class.

**My suggestion:**

If you want to only accept exact matches, you can create a helper method for it:

```
var hasClass = function (element, cls) {
    return element.getAttribute('class').then(function (classes) {
        return classes.split(' ').indexOf(cls) !== -1;
    });
};
```

You can use it like this (taking advantage of the fact that `expect` automatically resolves promises in Protractor):

```
expect(hasClass(element(by.name('getoffer')), 'ngDirty')).toBe(true);
```

Comment: This worked for me, with the mod that the class name had to be hyphen format not camel case, i.e `expect(hasClass(element(by.name('getoffer')), 'ng-dirty')).toBe(true);`

Comment: I'm  little unclear on what the function has class is doing, particularly where or what classes is when getting passed into the .then function, could someone enlighten me?

Comment: @ErikAGriffin: The hasClass function gets passed two arguments - an html element and a name of a class to check for. The function then gets the "class" attribute (the classes) that the element has. It splits the class string to get an array of classes. It then checks if the class you are looking for is in any positive index of the array. I assume it's a way to check for existence.

Comment: I've rewritten your four line function to this sexy ES6 one liner: hasClass = (element, className) => element.getAttribute('class').then( (classes) => classes.split(' ').indexOf(className) !== -1 );

Comment: In TypeScript:
async function hasClass(elm: ElementFinder, className: string): Promise<boolean> {
  const classNamesStr: string = await elm.getAttribute('class');
  const classNamesArr: string[] = classNamesStr.split(' ');
  return classNamesArr.includes(className);
}

Answer (score 57):

If you're using Protractor with Jasmine, you could use `toMatch` to match as a regular expression...

```
expect(element(by.name('getoffer')).getAttribute('class')).toMatch('ngDirty');
```

Also, note that `toContain` will match list items, if you need that.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the ideal way to do this, but at least it works as expected :)

Comment: No, I'd say it's probably not.  I'd expect `element` to return an object with an `hasClass` method, which you could wrap inside of an `expect` call...

Comment: `toContain` might be a better choice than `toMatch` in this case.

Comment: If you want to guard against partial matches, try something like `/(^|\s)ngDirty($|\s)/`.

Comment: you probably can use `.not.toContain` to check if it doesn't have the particular class or `.toContain` for checking if it exists

Answer (score 19):

Simplest is:

```
expect(element.getAttribute('class')).toContain("active");
```

Comment: This returns error `java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String` on Microsoft Edge

Comment: @Manolis how are you getting java exceptions in the web console for angularjs??

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried this?

```
const el = element(by.name('getoffer'));
expect(el.getAttribute('class')).toBe('ngDirty')
```

or a variation of the above...

Comment: The problem is, that the form has more than one class attached to.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the answer from Sergey K, you could also add a custom matcher to do this:

(coffeescript)

```
  beforeEach(()->
    this.addMatchers({
      toHaveClass: (expected)->
        @message = ()->
          "Expected #{@actual.locator_.value} to have class '#{expected}'"

        @actual.getAttribute('class').then((classes)->
          classes.split(' ').indexOf(expected) isnt -1
        )
    })
  )
```

Then you can use it in tests like this:

```
expect($('div#ugly')).toHaveClass('beautiful')
```

And you'll get the following error if it doesn't:

```
 Message:
   Expected div#ugly to have class beautiful
 Stacktrace:
   Error: Expected div#ugly to have class 'beautiful'
```

Answer (score 2):

I made this matcher, I had to wrap it in a promise and use 2 returns

```
this.addMatchers({
    toHaveClass: function(a) {
        return this.actual.getAttribute('class').then(function(cls){
            var patt = new RegExp('(^|\\s)' + a + '(\\s|$)');
            return patt.test(cls);
        });
    }
});
```

in my test i can now do stuf like this:

```
   var myDivs = element.all(by.css('div.myClass'));
   expect(myDivs.count()).toBe(3);

   // test for class
   expect(myDivs.get(0)).not.toHaveClass('active');
```

this also works when an element has multiple classes or when an element has no class attribute at all.

Answer (score 2):

```
function checkHasClass (selector, class_name) {
    // custom function returns true/false depending if selector has class name

    // split classes for selector into a list
    return $(selector).getAttribute('class').then(function(classes){
        var classes = classes.split(' ');
        if (classes.indexOf(class_name) > -1) return true;
        return false;
    });
}
```

This is how I do it at least, without the need to use the expect function. This function simply returns true if the class is inside the element and false if not. This also uses promises so you would use it like:

```
checkHasClass('#your-element', 'your-class').then(function(class_found){
    if (class_found) console.log("Your element has that class");
});
```

Edit: I just realized this is essentially the same as the top answer

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://gist.github.com/elgalu/94284ec0ac3e8a590507) a Jasmine 1.3.x custom `toHaveClass` matcher with negation `.not` support plus wait up to 5 seconds (or whatever you specify).

[Find the full custom matcher to be added on your onPrepare block in this gist](https://gist.github.com/elgalu/94284ec0ac3e8a590507)

#### Sample usage:

```
it('test the class finder custom matcher', function() {
    // These guys should pass OK given your user input
    // element starts with an ng-invalid class:
    expect($('#user_name')).toHaveClass('ng-invalid');
    expect($('#user_name')).not.toHaveClass('ZZZ');
    expect($('#user_name')).toNotHaveClass('ZZZ');
    expect($('#user_name')).not.toNotHaveClass('ng-invalid');
    // These guys should each fail:
    expect($('#user_name')).toHaveClass('ZZZ');
    expect($('#user_name')).not.toHaveClass('ng-invalid');
    expect($('#user_name')).toNotHaveClass('ng-invalid');
    expect($('#user_name')).not.toNotHaveClass('ZZZ');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this would be to use xpath and use `contains()`

Example:

```
var expectElementToHaveClass = function (className) {
    var path = by.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'"+ className +"')]");
    expect(element.all(path).count()).to.eventually.be.eq(1);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CSS parser to handle this by checking if an element with the given class exists:

```
expect(element(by.css('.form[name="getoffer"].ngDirty')).isPresent()).toBe(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you're solving a few problems:

1. how to get class. class is an html attribute and thus can be retrieved by this command (`await` is the recommended way these days)

```
let class = await element.getAttribute('class')
```

2. Once you got the value of a class, you want to assert it

```
// for exact value
expect(class).toBe("active");

// for partial match
expect(class).toContain("active");
// or
expect(class.includes("active")).toBe(true);

// BUT, keep in mind
expect('male').toContain('male');
expect('female').toContain('male');
// BOTH pass
```