# Click() and then() not working - Protractor

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor, end-to-end

I am writing a test with `protractor` and my aim is click an element and check if it has a specific `class`. The issue is that I am using `click()`, followed by `then()`, but I am getting the following error:

```
Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of null
```

The issue is located in the following chunk of code:

```
element(by.css('#region1 polygon:first-child')).click()
    .then(function(selected){
        expect(selected.getAttribute('class')).toContain('highlighted');
    });
```

Do you have an idea on how to solve this issue? Thanks in advance for your replies!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `click()` callback does not have an element itself as an argument. In other words, `selected` in your case is not an element.

Instead, just do it step by step and let the [Control Flow](http://www.protractortest.org/#/control-flow#promises-and-the-control-flow) queue do the job:

```
var elm = element(by.css('#region1 polygon:first-child'));

elm.click();
expect(elm.getAttribute('class')).toContain('highlighted');
```

Note that `toContain()` is not the best matcher to apply to the `class` attribute value. For example, this test would pass if an element would have a `not-highlighted` class. A better way to do that is to introduce a custom `toHaveClass` matcher, please see:

- [How to test if an element has class using Protractor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20268128/how-to-test-if-an-element-has-class-using-protractor)