# Add a locator at the same level to the variable

Tags: html, css, selenium, protractor, automated-tests

My goal is to find an element with id and class both. I do it like this:

```
    return element(by.css('#right.closed')).isPresent();
```

That is working fine. But I want to improve and introduce a variable for:

```
  public static rightPanel = element(by.css('#right'));
```

I want to use the rightPanel and on the fly with use of that variable add another condition at the same level:

```
   rightPanel.addConditionClassMustBeClosedAtThatElement.isPresent();
```

Is it doable ?

Comment: Seems to be  your talking  about element chaining concept. If i'm right,  Yes, we can do as you expected above

Comment: Chaining works, but this looks in the children of that first element. I want to look for insinde that element not its children.

Comment: can u paste html code for elements on which you want to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `addConditionClassMustBeClosedAtThatElement` can be implemented via [`getAttribute()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getAttribute):

```
rightPanel.isPresent().then(function (isPresent) {
    rightPanel.getAttribute("class").then(function (classes) {
        console.log(isPresent && classes.indexOf("closed") >= 0);
    });
});
```

Or, if were to add expectations via `expect()`:

```
expect(rightPanel.isPresent()).toBe(true);
expect(rightPanel).toHaveClass("closed");
```

where [`toHaveClass` is a custom jasmine matcher](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28041037/771848).

Comment: rightPanel.isPresent().then(function (isPresent) {
    rightPanel.getAttribute("class").then(function (classes) {
        console.log(isPresent && classes.indexOf("closed") >= 0);
    });
});